# How the first tree in gradient boosting classifier is constructed and the split criteria

Tags: boosting

I am aware how GB classifiers are constructed as regression trees and predictions are made, but not sure how the initial tree and node splitting for it is done.

Can someone please explain how the first tree in GBM  (classifier) is constructed, and how the node splitting criteria for the first tree is decided. 
I am not sure, what we are predicting for the first tree (even assuming a constant is initialized, how gradient of loss are computed from the constant).

If mse is the node split criteria, what is it composed of (I mean, squared difference of what values??).
Thank you.

Comment: I have answered this in the question in the thread: [First Iteration in Gradient Boosting Algorithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427213). If there something more specific you need, please do tell! :)

Comment: @usεr11852, thank you for the response. The explanations show how it works for predicting a continuous value ( regression problem), and I understand even in classification we predict the log odds (and hence a regression problem). But in case of classification, wondering how the initial constant before the first iteration is assigned and what is the constant assigned to (log odds??). If the initial constant is assigned to log odds, how do we know, what the true log odds (for true y) should be to calculate the loss-because we only know the true class - say 0 or 1 of sample and not true log odds.

Comment: This is a bit implementation specific. In most new implementations the exact value of the initial constant depends on the learning rate $\eta$ and/or we can go ahead and directly set it ourselves. Usually we would "boost from average" in the sense that we would calculate the sample log odds despite not being "the true log odds". Assuming that we optimise appropriately, the values of the first iteration are not of great importance. It might affect convergence speed in some cases but realistically if we are prepared to do hundreds of iteration the actual initial values are not very influential.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you. can you please elaborate on how 'boost from average" is used to calculate the sample log odds? The link's answer (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204154/classification-with-gradient-boosting-how-to-keep-the-prediction-in-0-1) says that the loss is expressed in terms of true y and predicted log odds and hence my understanding is that we won't need true log odds at all. is this correct or the 'boost from average'?
  
Also, if you can, can you please answer the following https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452108/steps-in-gradient-boosting-algorithm

Comment: I am in full agreement with the answer linked. I am just pointing out the the first estimate of $p_i$ will be the average value observed. We would simply apply the inverse link to it and get $L_i$.

Comment: Cool. I will check the new question within the week.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you very much for your kind responses.